# Collapse GUI only using WPF

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

Is there a way to show / hide gui when I click on another GUI element? I am doing MAUI GUI and using CollectionView I generate list of buttons. When I click on one I want to show option 1 and 2 for that item, if I click on another I want to show it´s options and hide the old ones.

I use MVVM, that is why I ask for GUI option only.

[image]

Code for list:

```
 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyItem">
                        <StackLayout>
                    <Frame Margin="10,5">

                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>


                            </Grid>

                    </Frame>

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Option 1" Margin="5"/>

                                <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Option 2" Margin="5"/>

                            </Grid>

                        </StackLayout>

                    </DataTemplate>

            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            

        </CollectionView>
```

Comment: When you say `WPF`, do you mean the `XAML` code you show? Both WPF and Maui use variants of XAML. But Maui XAML isn't exactly identical to WPF. Just call it XAML. Unless I misunderstand your question, replace all references to WPF in your question, including title and tag, with XAML.

Comment: add a `bool` to your model and have the buttons toggle the value of the bool.  Then bind the `IsVisible` property of your UI elements to that bool

Comment: @Somachr You can try my solution in my answer. It works well. For more information about `TapGestureRecognizer`, you can check this doc by official: [Recognize a tap gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-7.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand, your case needs to implement behavior which could be expressed by phrase ***"only one of many"***.

Jason's solution (`bool` property bound to `IsVisible` of your control) will work, however it will get messy along with your button count rising - you would need to handle **every single button and it's bound property** - why would you want to do that?

In addition i'm sure you will eventually need this again in another `View`, so you would have to repeat that - it's not really **DRY**, isn't it?

I would suggest to use more **reusable** approach.

**1. Create a converter class:**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(bool))]
public class IsEqualConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return targetType == typeof(bool)
            ? Equals(value, parameter)
            : throw new InvalidOperationException("Converter can only convert to value of type bool.");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid call - one way only");
    }
}
```

**2.Reference your converter in desired `View` :**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converters:IsEqualConverter x:Key="IsEqualConverter" />    
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

**3. Set the `SelectionMode` of your `CollectionView` to `Single`.**

```
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single">
```

**4. Bind `IsVisible` of your `Grid`, to `SelectedItem` of your `CollectionView` using syntax below:**

```
<Grid IsVisible="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CollectionView}}, Path=SelectedItem.Name}}">
```

Assuming `Name` is unique of course.

**[Optional]
5. Create and implement `Interface` providing unique identification.**

```
public interface IIdentifyUniquely
{
    public Guid UniqueIdentifier { get; }
}

public class MyItem : IIdentifyUniquely
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueIdentifier { get; }

    public MyItem()
    {
        UniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Then bind to implemented `UniqueIdentifier` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TapGestureRecognizer` attached to Frame:

```
<ScrollView>
    <CollectionView>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyItem">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame Margin="10,5">
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                    <Grid IsVisible="false">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Option 1" Margin="5"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Option 2" Margin="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ScrollView>
```

And Page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class NewPage : ContentPage
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    public NewPage() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        ... 
    }
    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid.IsVisible = false;

        Frame frame = (Frame)sender;
        StackLayout stacklayout = (StackLayout)frame.Parent;
        grid = (Grid)stacklayout.Children[stacklayout.Children.Count - 1];

        grid.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will point out here few options you have, using "MVVM and UI only"

1. You can use triggers.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-7.0

With this you can make your UI dependent on properties of your Model.

2. You can use Styling and VisualStates.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states?view=net-maui-7.0

With this you can change the appearance of your UI Elements, depending on their visual state. For example, if you decide make use of "Selected" property of your item.

3. You can use alternatives for showing additional UI elements for each item. For example - SwipeView.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview?view=net-maui-7.0
4. You can try writing your own, reusable ControlTemplate.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-7.0
5. You can get 3rd party controls. Here is one of the CommunityToolkit, that does something very similar:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/expander

There are really so many ways to handle your problem. You can also do what Jason said, and just bind to IsVisible and deal with it manually.